# Why would i only get ConcurrentModificationException only on 1 of three web servers that have the same exact ear deployed

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, iterator, concurrentmodification

We have a peoplesoft application deployed on three identical WebLogic servers.  A netscaler appliance load balances between them as well as maintaining session stickiness.  The delivered Peoplesoft ear application is delivered by Oracle and not customized by us in any way.

One of the three web servers exhibits ConcurrentModificationExceptions.  We have this same ear deployed on many other servers throughout our enterprise but this is the only one that experiences this issue.  The issue is so bad that we have had to keep the server down and out of the server farm.  So now we load balance across 2 of the original 3 servers.

As a customer of Oracle, **we dont have access to any of the source code**.  This makes it difficult to narrow down the problem.

Since this ear is exactly the same as the ears on the properly functioning servers I am thinking that the "difference" must be something outside of the ear that is causing the problem.

Here is what I have figured out:

The exception is occurring when the application is trying to obtain a thread from the JOLT connection pool.  This pool is managed by a java linked list object.  The thread tries to iterate over the linked list looking for an available connection to connect to the App server with.  (Background: The peoplesoft ear (deployed within the WebLogic App Server) connects to another tier (an App Server consisting of C++ and java code communicating via Tuxedo controlled IPC objects like queues, shared memory ...) using JOLT.  The jolt connections are pooled for efficiency.  The thread fails before being assigned a connection from the pool.  Another thread (I assume) iterates over the linkedlist and then causes the ConcurrentModificationException.

Some threads are able to successfully obtain a connection from the jolt pool but when traffic increases so does the likelyhood that the ConcurrentModificationException will occur.

When i say that I checked something I mean that I compared them to the same items on the servers without the problem

I have checked many things in search of the cause:

- checked and reinstalled weblogic
- checked and reinstalled peopletools
- Checked and redeployed the peoplesoft application
- Check and reinstalled java
- used a different version of java
- Checked the classpath
- Checked the environment variables
- Checked the ulimits
- Checked the java command line options
- Checked the operating system version, tech levels and service packs version
- checked the OS filesets

I am running out of ideas on what to check.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException       java.util.ConcurrentModificationException<br>^M
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:977)^M
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:899)^M
        at psft.pt8.net.JoltSessionPool.getJoltSession(JoltSessionPool.java:276)^M
        at psft.pt8.net.NetSession.getJoltSession(NetSession.java:693)^M
        at psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc.sendRequest(NetReqRepSvc.java:556)^M
        at psft.pt8.net.NetService.requestService(NetService.java:167)^M
        at psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc.requestService(NetReqRepSvc.java:354)^M
        at psft.pt8.jb.JBEntry.processRequest(JBEntry.java:673)^M
        at psft.pt8.psc.onActionGen(psc.java:3045)^M
        at psft.pt8.psc.onAction(psc.java:1753)^M
        at psft.pt8.psc.onAction(psc.java:1742)^M
        at psft.pt8.psc.service(psc.java:963)^M
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)^M
        at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:274)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)^M
        at psft.pt8.psfilter.doFilter(psfilter.java:88)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3706)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)^M
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)^M
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)^M
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)^M
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)^M
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)^M
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)^M
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)^M
```

What , outside of the java ear could impact this?

Comment: Are all of the servers running exactly the same version of Java?

Comment: Yes Dan, All three servers are running the exact same version of java.  I did multiple things to verify that they were the exact same (other than java -version).  I wrote a script to crawl the entire java deployment and produce a message hash (sha-1) of every file under in and then did the same on the working servers.  I then used various compare tools to look for any differences but there were none

Answer (score 0):

A ConcurrentModificationException is almost always a coding error. The code was not prepared for multiple threads running or is flawed. The unfortunate part is that this can happen randomly such as when two threads try to modify a resource at the same time. The other scenario would be a single thread modifies a resource it's currently iterating using a fail-fast iterator. The second scenario would happen predictably.

> Another thread (I assume) iterates over the linkedlist and then causes
>   the ConcurrentModificationException.

**Another thread would have to modify the linkedlist by perhaps adding or removing an element. This is a coding oversight.**

1. Did you contact the software company that provided you peoplesoft? They need to fix their code and make `psft.pt8.net.JoltSessionPool.getJoltSession(JoltSessionPool.java:276)` thread safe.
2. The other option for this server would be to run it with only a single worker thread. (Configured for the Java program so it doesn't open multiple Java threads.) This could be a temporary solution until the software developers fix their bug.
3. Verify that the weblogic servlet has not been misconfigured and allowed multiple threads when it wasn't supposed to. (Maybe the peoplesoft code isn't supposed to be contended by multiple threads.)

> Why does this happen on one specific server?

If it's load balanced, consider if the server was getting most of the load due to its physical location in relation to users of the web service. More activity would increase the chance of threads competing.

Comment: I have contacted the software provide (Oracle/Peoplesoft) but since they can't reproduce the problem they aren't really dedicating any time to this.  This code is deployed in tens of thousands of companies and is working in high demand/high usage environments without a problem.

Comment: I considered the concept that since this is the first server in the load balancing string that it might get more load than the other servers do.  But if that was a contributing factor then I would expect to see if on the second server once we removed the first (troublesome) server from the load balancer.  Originally there were three servers all handling approximately 33% of traffic.  After we removed the bad server the two remaining servers handled 50% of the traffic, without encountering this same issue.

Comment: Another option is you finding the problem, by decompiling their jar if your license permits such as using java dec, or intelliJ, then reporting it so it gets fixed faster.

Comment: I dont think that we have the permission to decompile, unfortunately

Comment: Here is an update, I turned off java pooling and the concurrentmodificationexception went away.  Of course, this is not a fix, we were convinced that the issue was occurring while iterating over the jolt thread pool so turning off pooling would be a temporary workaround, and it is.  Unfortunately we will be running less efficiently while the pooling is off, but at least it gives us some respite.  I still want to try turning off JIT/AOT compiling to see what impact that has

Comment: I took someone's suggestion for turning off JIT compiling to see if that had an impact, and it did.  I re-enabled jolt pooling, and turned off JIT by adding the JAVA OPTION: -Djava.compiler=NONE to the java command line.  The web server went from a 40 seconds startup to about a 20 minute startup, but it seems to have had an impact on the issue.  Of course, this isn't an acceptable long term solution, but it does help us to narrow down the cause of this problem a little more.  We are also trying to determine how much of a performance hit the end user is experiencing because of this change.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

> I am running out of ideas on what to check.

How about the server hardware.  Any chance it is a server with less memory or fewer or slower CPUs which causes different interactions under load?

If it *never* happens on the other servers then something is very wrong.  Do you have any way to copy the hard-drives from a working server onto the broken one?  It would seem to me that there is some sort of configuration difference or something.

> Another thread (I assume) iterates over the LinkedList and then causes the ConcurrentModificationException.

It is actually fine for 2 threads to iterate over the same `LinkedList`.  What is not fine is if the list changes while a thread is iterating over it.  It is actually *more* typical for single-threaded applications to see CMEs.  The thread could remove something from the list under circumstances that would cause the iteration to throw.

As a hack, depending on your level of desperation, you could provide a different `LinkedList` class on the classpath and instrument it or even add locks to it to understand or maybe even protect against the problem.